# What is the Scala way to do this? Family of case classes serialized as Json representing a series of operations

Tags: scala, types, gremlin

I am having some frustrations trying to find the right way to do something in Scala. I have a series of operations, basically functions, encoded as a json list. I want to parse these list elements into operations and perform the operations one after the other to get some result.

I have the operations encoded as case classes:

```
sealed trait Operation

case class VertexOperation(vertex: String) extends Operation {
  def operate(input: ScalaGraph): GremlinScala[Vertex, HNil] = {
    input.V.hasLabel(vertex)
  }
}

case class InOperation(in: String) extends Operation {
  def operate[Labels <: HList](input: GremlinScala[Vertex, Labels]): GremlinScala[Vertex, Labels] = {
    input.in(in)
  }
}

..............
```

https://github.com/bmeg/leprechaun/blob/master/src/main/scala/leprechaun/Leprechaun.scala#L13-L68

and the json parsed into a list of these operations:

```
object Query {
  class OperationSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Operation](format => ({
    case JObject(List(JField("vertex", JString(vertex)))) => VertexOperation(vertex)
    case JObject(List(JField("in", JString(in)))) => InOperation(in)
    case JObject(List(JField("out", JString(out)))) => 
    case JObject(List(JField("outVertex", JString(outVertex)))) => OutVertexOperation(outVertex)
    ...........
  }, {
    case VertexOperation(vertex) => JObject(JField("vertex", JString(vertex)))
    case InOperation(in) => JObject(JField("in", JString(in)))
    ..........
  }))

  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new OperationSerializer()

  def fromJson(json: JValue): Query = {
    json.extract[Query]
  }

  def fromString(raw: String): Query = {
    val json = parse(raw)
    fromJson(json)
  }
}
```

https://github.com/bmeg/leprechaun/blob/master/src/main/scala/leprechaun/Leprechaun.scala#L70-L96

Awesome. Now comes the horror. I want to perform these operations one by one, starting with some value, and applying each operation in turn upon the result of the last. Easy, sounds like a reduction...

Except the operations have different signatures. Now I am hosed. This is the only thing I could come up with that works, that violates everything about how I think I am supposed to use Scala:

```
case class Query(query: List[Operation]) {
  // def operate[R, In <: HList, G](graph: ScalaGraph) (implicit p: Prepend[In, ::[G, HNil]]): R = {
  def operate[R](graph: ScalaGraph): R = {
    var anvil: Any = graph
    def op[M](operation: Operation) {
      operation match {
        case VertexOperation(vertex) => anvil = operation.asInstanceOf[VertexOperation].operate(anvil.asInstanceOf[ScalaGraph])
        case InOperation(in) => anvil = operation.asInstanceOf[InOperation].operate(anvil.asInstanceOf[GremlinScala[Vertex, HList]])
        case OutVertexOperation(outVertex) => anvil = operation.asInstanceOf[OutVertexOperation].operate(anvil.asInstanceOf[GremlinScala[Edge, HList]])
        .............
      }
    }

    query.foreach(x => op(x))
    anvil.asInstanceOf[R]
  }
}
```

https://github.com/bmeg/leprechaun/blob/master/src/main/scala/leprechaun/Leprechaun.scala#L98-L122

Surely, this is wrong. I am using a `var` of type `Any` to hold the value being operated on, and match the type of the `Operation` and cast it, along with the input, to actually call the operation. It feels wrong, but I can't get anything else to work.

I actually have a hopeful implementation using an HList below that:

```
trait ApplyOperationDefault extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[T, L <: HList] = at[T, L] ((_, acc) => acc)
}

object ApplyOperation extends ApplyOperationDefault {
  implicit def vertex[T, L <: HList, S <: HList] = at[VertexOperation, ScalaGraph] ((t, acc) => t.operate(acc))
  implicit def has[M, T, L <: HList, S <: HList] = at[HasOperation[M], GremlinScala[Vertex, S]] ((t, acc) => t.operate(acc))
  implicit def as[A, T, L <: HList, In <: HList](implicit p: Prepend[In, ::[A, HNil]]) = at[AsOperation, GremlinScala[A, In]] ((t, acc) => t.operate(acc))
  implicit def in[T, L <: HList, S <: HList] = at[InOperation, GremlinScala[Vertex, S]] ((t, acc) => t.operate(acc))
  implicit def out[T, L <: HList, S <: HList] = at[OutOperation, GremlinScala[Vertex, S]] ((t, acc) => t.operate(acc))
  .............
}

object Operation {
  def process[Input, Output, A <: HList](operations: A, input: Input) (implicit folder: RightFolder.Aux[A, Input, ApplyOperation.type, Output]): Output = {
    operations.foldRight(input) (ApplyOperation)
  }
}
```

https://github.com/bmeg/leprechaun/blob/master/src/main/scala/leprechaun/Leprechaun.scala#L124-L144

But, I can't find a way to translate the list of `Operations` parsed from Json at runtime into an HList... is there a way to do that?

The code I am referencing works (you can clone and test it with `sbt test`:  https://github.com/bmeg/leprechaun ) but there has to be a better way.

Any insight appreciated, thank you for your help!

Comment: "But, I can't find a way to translate the list of Operations parsed from Json at runtime into an HList... is there a way to do that?" Everything about an HList is known at Compile time: it's length, the types of each element, everything! The solution you are attempting to code simply won't work since the types don't (can't; damn JVM) exist at Runtime. Instead of types you'll have to stick with values. Sorry ;-(

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was my understanding as well. I asked because I have seen some voodoo of constructing HLists at runtime that I didn't totally understand... So then I need to find some other alternative to the "anvil" trick here.

Comment: The voodoo for constructing types from values is called [Type Providers](https://github.com/travisbrown/type-provider-examples) and works with macros. But I don't think it's a solution for you.

Comment: Question: I'm looking at GremlinScala 3.2.3.2 and wondering: if `GremlinScala` isn't a subtype of `ScalaGraph`, how are you even able to one to `operate`?  i.e. given that `graph: ScalaGraph`, and `anvil = graph`, how is it that `anvil.instanceOf[GremlinScala[...]]` doesn't crash every time?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your primary question, but you can replace

```
case VertexOperation(vertex) => 
  anvil = operation.asInstanceOf[VertexOperation].blah
```

with

```
case op @ VertexOperation(_) => 
  anvil = op.blah
```

to eliminate some of the `.asInstanceOf`